# Tag score calculation

Tags: support

I can list all my answers for a certain tag. The list includes the votes, and negative votes already subtracted to my knowledge (in this specific case it's the tag `networking`). But the score doesn't add up. Is there some delay in the calculation or [some negative votes I'm not aware of](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63835/what-are-tag-badges-how-do-they-work/63836#63836)?

**Afterthoughts:** To get a quick overview I created the list by clicking a tag in the little section that shows the top-scored tags for my user and sorted it by score...  turned out it also includs questions and shows the negativ scored tags on the last page (which I didn't notice since I skipped everything after the first 0 score answer). It works fine with a manual search `user:201818 [networking] is:answer` Thanks to NotTheDr01ds for helping me to find my misstake.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by the score doesn't add up?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/what-are-the-badges-i-can-earn-on-each-site-and-what-are-the-exact-criteria-for#68395

Comment: @Mokubai thx, the post link is already included in the question I linked to, unless I overlooked s.th. it doesn't provide an answer

Comment: @DavidPostill, I mean the tag score

Comment: @Ramhound I always do (see last edit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But the score doesn't add up.

It's unclear from your question what you *think* your score should be or why you think it is incorrect.  It appears to me to be absolutely correct.

From the post that you linked:

> A tag score is basically the combined total of all the upvotes (+1) and downvotes (-1) you've accumulated on answers under that specific tag (votes on questions do not count). Acceptance of an answer doesn't have any weight in the score.

Note that the score is *not* based on reputation gained, but absolute votes.

As of this post, you currently have:

- [answered 99 questions](https://superuser.com/search?q=user%3A201818+%5Bnetworking%5D+is%3Aanswer) in the [networking](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/networking) tag
- 44 of those have a net positive score (more upvotes than downvotes)
- 2 have a net negative score (more downvotes than upvotes)
- 55 have a score of 0 (either no upvotes/downvotes or an equal number of each)
- The sum of the scores in that tag is 77, which is what your profile currently reports.  Of course, that's one more than two days ago when you posted this.

The questions with a non-zero score:

| Question | Score |
| --- | --- |
| [The ip address returned by whatismyipaddress.com belong to who?](https://superuser.com/questions/1725902/the-ip-address-returned-by-whatismyipaddress-com-belong-to-who/1725904#1725904) | 1 |
| [What is the use of three separate routing table entries for loopback?](https://superuser.com/questions/1723094/what-is-the-use-of-three-separate-routing-table-entries-for-loopback/1723110#1723110) | 3 |
| [Why does windows try and use a network with no internet when connected to two networks at once?](https://superuser.com/questions/1722939/why-does-windows-try-and-use-a-network-with-no-internet-when-connected-to-two-ne/1722972#1722972) | 1 |
| [If using a switch that supports VLAN can some devices connect directly to the router?](https://superuser.com/questions/1722756/if-using-a-switch-that-supports-vlan-can-some-devices-connect-directly-to-the-ro/1722783#1722783) | 1 |
| [Local DNS - can I put it on the Internet?](https://superuser.com/questions/1715851/local-dns-can-i-put-it-on-the-internet/1715863#1715863) | 2 |
| [TP-LINK Archer C7 limits connectivity on devices picked (seemingly) randomly](https://superuser.com/questions/1710095/tp-link-archer-c7-limits-connectivity-on-devices-picked-seemingly-randomly/1713055#1713055) | 1 |
| [Network switch stops working until power cycled, but replacing the switch and the router changes nothing](https://superuser.com/questions/1712107/network-switch-stops-working-until-power-cycled-but-replacing-the-switch-and-th/1712322#1712322) | 1 |
| [Connect two Modem/Routers](https://superuser.com/questions/1709215/connect-two-modem-routers/1709299#1709299) | 1 |
| [Cannot ping a Windows 11 machine](https://superuser.com/questions/1683853/cannot-ping-a-windows-11-machine/1708357#1708357) | 1 |
| [Difference between external port and internal port in port forwarding?](https://superuser.com/questions/1708129/difference-between-external-port-and-internal-port-in-port-forwarding/1708130#1708130) | 5 |
| [Connecting sites together to use DHCP](https://superuser.com/questions/1706183/connecting-sites-together-to-use-dhcp/1706198#1706198) | 1 |
| [Ping IP address routed to wrong destination](https://superuser.com/questions/1705429/ping-ip-address-routed-to-wrong-destination/1705457#1705457) | 1 |
| [Is my PC visible or accessible to other PCs if I have connected to the internet through PPPoE?](https://superuser.com/questions/1672718/is-my-pc-visible-or-accessible-to-other-pcs-if-i-have-connected-to-the-internet/1672740#1672740) | 1 |
| [Two set of properties for a single wifi connection](https://superuser.com/questions/1663260/two-set-of-properties-for-a-single-wifi-connection/1663270#1663270) | 1 |
| [Unable to access my local web server via WAN-IP (provided by ISP)](https://superuser.com/questions/1662994/unable-to-access-my-local-web-server-via-wan-ip-provided-by-isp/1663007#1663007) | 1 |
| [Hostname mapping to LAN IPs in Router?](https://superuser.com/questions/1661615/hostname-mapping-to-lan-ips-in-router/1661621#1661621) | 1 |
| [Home network configuration issue](https://superuser.com/questions/1651779/home-network-configuration-issue/1651848#1651848) | 1 |
| [Sync alerts over network](https://superuser.com/questions/1651359/sync-alerts-over-network/1651367#1651367) | 1 |
| [How to make shared folders of different computers in a LAN available across two different networks, when only one PC has access to two networks?](https://superuser.com/questions/1648042/how-to-make-shared-folders-of-different-computers-in-a-lan-available-across-two/1648160#1648160) | 1 |
| [Is it possible for each layer to give incomplete data to the lower layer?](https://superuser.com/questions/1647983/is-it-possible-for-each-layer-to-give-incomplete-data-to-the-lower-layer/1647995#1647995) | 2 |
| [VoIP and computer on separate VLANs through one cable](https://superuser.com/questions/1647831/voip-and-computer-on-separate-vlans-through-one-cable/1647855#1647855) | 1 |
| [How can I connect DNS server to two networks in CISCO?](https://superuser.com/questions/1644706/how-can-i-connect-dns-server-to-two-networks-in-cisco/1644708#1644708) | 1 |
| [1 Modem with 3 separate networks](https://superuser.com/questions/1632990/1-modem-with-3-separate-networks/1632996#1632996) | 1 |
| [Home network including Mac mini as DNS and DHCP server](https://superuser.com/questions/1630347/home-network-including-mac-mini-as-dns-and-dhcp-server/1630360#1630360) | 1 |
| [How to auto switch WIFI Router based on internet connectivity?](https://superuser.com/questions/1595216/how-to-auto-switch-wifi-router-based-on-internet-connectivity/1595227#1595227) | -2 |
| [How to route internet traffic seperately to local traffic](https://superuser.com/questions/1594970/how-to-route-internet-traffic-seperately-to-local-traffic/1594977#1594977) | 1 |
| [Wifi connected and shows internet access but cant use internet](https://superuser.com/questions/1594929/wifi-connected-and-shows-internet-access-but-cant-use-internet/1594980#1594980) | 2 |
| [how to make a pc to be connected with another pc directly, while still let it connect to the internet via network cable](https://superuser.com/questions/1594712/how-to-make-a-pc-to-be-connected-with-another-pc-directly-while-still-let-it-co/1594718#1594718) | 2 |
| [Wake On Lan doesn't work on Repeater](https://superuser.com/questions/1593962/wake-on-lan-doesnt-work-on-repeater/1594017#1594017) | 1 |
| [Networking subnetting](https://superuser.com/questions/1594262/networking-subnetting/1594280#1594280) | 2 |
| [Hosting different services on one server](https://superuser.com/questions/1591860/hosting-different-services-on-one-server/1591863#1591863) | -1 |
| [Can't manage to reach home server through VPN tunnel from my Institution LAN](https://superuser.com/questions/1590949/cant-manage-to-reach-home-server-through-vpn-tunnel-from-my-institution-lan/1590954#1590954) | 1 |
| [How does a network device update its MAC table?](https://superuser.com/questions/1590518/how-does-a-network-device-update-its-mac-table/1590566#1590566) | 2 |
| [Working remotely over VPN with Win10 and Windows Server (AD, SMB)?](https://superuser.com/questions/1590127/working-remotely-over-vpn-with-win10-and-windows-server-ad-smb/1590141#1590141) | 1 |
| [Does my home have ethernet or telephone wiring running through it?](https://superuser.com/questions/1590084/does-my-home-have-ethernet-or-telephone-wiring-running-through-it/1590091#1590091) | 1 |
| [Connect local IIS server to internet](https://superuser.com/questions/1588221/connect-local-iis-server-to-internet/1589343#1589343) | 2 |
| [Windows 10 connected to two different networks, both having same subnet mask](https://superuser.com/questions/1585375/windows-10-connected-to-two-different-networks-both-having-same-subnet-mask/1585448#1585448) | 1 |
| [Issue in network configuration](https://superuser.com/questions/1584852/issue-in-network-configuration/1584910#1584910) | 1 |
| [Should you be able to access your modem's web interface when the internet is down?](https://superuser.com/questions/1579369/should-you-be-able-to-access-your-modems-web-interface-when-the-internet-is-dow/1579385#1579385) | 1 |
| [Using a dedicated landline for internet?](https://superuser.com/questions/1576724/using-a-dedicated-landline-for-internet/1576742#1576742) | 2 |
| [Redundant routes between switches](https://superuser.com/questions/1574931/redundant-routes-between-switches/1576060#1576060) | 1 |
| [Asus Router share internet connection with USB connected device](https://superuser.com/questions/1487842/asus-router-share-internet-connection-with-usb-connected-device/1489615#1489615) | 2 |
| [Why "Connection-specific DNS Suffix" is only (default) available for wired connection, not for wireless](https://superuser.com/questions/1366226/why-connection-specific-dns-suffix-is-only-default-available-for-wired-conne/1369850#1369850) | 1 |
| [In a symlink pointing to '127.0.1.1:+xxxxx', what is the plus character for?](https://superuser.com/questions/1363677/in-a-symlink-pointing-to-127-0-1-1xxxxx-what-is-the-plus-character-for/1363683#1363683) | 22 |
| [Enter Network Credentials](https://superuser.com/questions/1362240/enter-network-credentials/1362251#1362251) | 1 |
| [Access point with different SSID doesn't work](https://superuser.com/questions/1340161/access-point-with-different-ssid-doesnt-work/1340168#1340168) | 1 |
| **Total** | **77** |

Side-note:

For those who want to run similar queries, here's how I did it using [Nushell](https://www.nushell.sh) and the [Stack Exchange API](https://api.stackexchange.com).

First, obtain the API method and arguments you need from the [corresponding doc page](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs).  In this case, I needed a "user's questions", which is [this page](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/answers-on-users).  The API site includes the ability for you to build the method with your arguments.  I needed:

- Albin's (Super User ID: 201818) answers
- Change the site, of course, to Super User
- Edit the "Filter" to add in tags, title, and link

And the resulting URI/method it gives me is:

```
/2.3/users/201818/answers?order=desc&sort=activity&site=superuser&filter=!6VvPDzQHaquV_
```

With that, in Nushell:

```
def getStackAPIPageLoop [ baseUri:any page?:any --help (-h) ] {
    let page = if ( $page == null ) {1} else {$page}
    let pageUri = ((echo $baseUri "&page=" $page) | str collect)
    let re = (http $pageUri | from json )
    print $re
    
    if ($re.has_more) {
        $re.items | append (getStackAPIPageLoop $baseUri ($page + 1))
    } else {
        $re.items
    }
}

let baseUri = "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.3/users/201818/answers?order=desc&sort=activity&site=superuser&filter=!6VvPDzQHaquV_"

# If you have a API key, add it, as you'll get a higher quota

let answers = getStackAPIPageLoop $baseUri
```

At this point, the `$answers` variable contains a list of all of the user's questions and the requested metadata that we can parse as desired.  E.g.:

```
$answers |
    where { |it| "networking" in  $it.tags } |
    where { |it| $it.score != 0 } |
    length

# 46

$answers |
    where { |it| "networking" in  $it.tags } |
    get score |
    math sum

# 77

$answers |
    where { |it| "networking" in  $it.tags } |
    where { |it| $it.score != 0 } |
    each { |answer| { "Question": $"[($answer.title)]\(($answer.link)\)" , "Score": $answer.score } } | 
    to md |
    clip.exe

# Replace clip.exe with your OS's clipboard app.  This will create the markdown table above (minus the total, which I added manually) that you can simply paste directly into Stack's markdown editor.
```

---

Today's histogram based on the previous comment:

```
╭───┬───────┬───────┬──────────┬────────────┬───────────────────────────────────────────────────────╮
│ # │ value │ count │ quantile │ percentage │                       frequency                       │
├───┼───────┼───────┼──────────┼────────────┼───────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ 0 │    -2 │     1 │     0.01 │ 1.00%      │ *                                                     │
│ 1 │    -1 │     1 │     0.01 │ 1.00%      │ *                                                     │
│ 2 │     0 │    53 │     0.53 │ 53.00%     │ ***************************************************** │
│ 3 │     1 │    33 │     0.33 │ 33.00%     │ *********************************                     │
│ 4 │     2 │     9 │     0.09 │ 9.00%      │ *********                                             │
│ 5 │     3 │     1 │     0.01 │ 1.00%      │ *                                                     │
│ 6 │     5 │     1 │     0.01 │ 1.00%      │ *                                                     │
│ 7 │    22 │     1 │     0.01 │ 1.00%      │ *                                                     │
╰───┴───────┴───────┴──────────┴────────────┴───────────────────────────────────────────────────────╯
```

Comment: I missed the negative scores (I sorted by votes), those were the votes I was missing thanks!

Comment: @Albin Ah, I think I understand.  You stopped when you got to the "0's", missing the ones under that ...  That makes sense!

Comment: @Albin I essentially just used a Stack Exchange API [query](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/answers-on-users#order=desc&sort=activity&ids=201818&filter=!6VvPDzQHaquV_&site=superuser&run=true) through Nushell as mentioned in [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/701415/432493).

Comment: exactly that... thanks, for the API link, interesting, I will try that out...

Comment: I just recalculated, I have 35*1 + 9*2 + 1*3 + 1*5 + 1*22 = 83, 83-3=80, my score is currently 77 (the last two +1 upvotes on the tag were today and on the 11th), assuming today's upvote is not calculated yet, the score should be 79, shouldn't it?

Comment: @Albin I'm showing a calculated score of 78 at the moment.  I show only 33*1.  Assuming today's upvote is not included, it sounds like 77 (displayed) is still correct.

Comment: you are correct, the default search, when you click on the tag in the answer section, still included questions (I parsed the HTML output), I did a manual search `user:201818 [networking] is:answer` and parsed again... voila, I got 33*1...  shouldn't have skipped the assert! thanks again. Quick&dirty solutions s.t. just bite you in the a*** ;)

Comment: @Albin Ah yes, I ran into that too when trying to validate whether my API script was returning the right number of answers.